# Pass FirebaseFirestore reference in Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-cloud-firestore

I need to send a FirebaseFirestore reference of a collection in intents from one activity to another which will be used to add documents by the second activity. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the path of the document as a string as an extra in the intent.  You can use [getPath()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#getPath()) to get the path from a DocumentReference, then use that same string to build a new DocumentReference by passing it to the [document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#document(java.lang.String)) method of FirebaseFirestore.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getPath() and then passing it to document reference.

Example:

Getting path from the reference

```
String documentId = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().getPath();

                // Bring users to View Event when clicking on viewEventButton
                holder.viewEventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewEventActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("documentId",documentId);
                        ((MainPageActivity) getActivity()).startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Getting Document from String path

```
        String documentId = getIntent().getStringExtra("documentId");
        String documentName = documentId.substring(documentId.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        // TODO how to reflect document path based on the event that users click on the app -> documentPath -> SharedPreferences from HomePage
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Events").document(documentName);
```